# can't load or replace XML of fragment but run the code in new fragment?

Tags: android, replace, fragment, fragmenttransaction

Why don't load the fragment_signup.XML just load the Toast and code in signup_Fragment ?!

**login_fragment.java**

```
private void init(){
        linktosignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager,new signup_fragment()).commit();
            }
        });
```

**signup_fragment**

```
public class signup_fragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup,container,false);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this is signup !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment_container**

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomnavigationview"
        android:layout_below="@id/winnersview">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

**fragment_signup.XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/signuper"
    android:background="@color/BoxBackgroundDark">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25454354351"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Toast show in signup_fragment but don't load the XML

Comment: Dont use viewpager as fragment container.Use FrameLayout as container.

Comment: the problem still there !!!

Comment: Can you share you project?

Comment: Ok let me check your link project

Comment: Check this :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KtlCgdfl1oTmMjrr2x8i44lww6ob6QSa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it work thank you. but why my code does not work why fragment don't replace?

Comment: Because of you are changing fragment of viewpager,you should replace fragment inside login fragment.